# temp store full when iterating over large amount sqlite3 records

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I have a large SQLite db where I am joining a 3.5M-row table onto itself. I use SQLite since it is the serialization format of my python3 application and the flatfile format is important in my workflow. When iterating over the rows of this join (around 55M rows) using:

```
cursor.execute('SELECT DISTINCT p.pid, pp.pname, pp.pid FROM proteins'
               'AS p JOIN proteins AS pp USING(pname) ORDER BY p.pid')
for row in cursor:
    # do stuff with row.
```

`EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN` gives the following:

```
0|0|0|SCAN TABLE proteins AS p USING INDEX pid_index (~1000000 rows)
0|1|1|SEARCH TABLE proteins AS pp USING INDEX pname_index (pname=?) (~10 rows)
0|0|0|USE TEMP B-TREE FOR DISTINCT
```

sqlite3 errors with "database or disk is full" after say 1.000.000 rows, which seems to indicate a full SQLite on-disk tempstore. Since I have enough RAM on my current box, that can be solved by setting the tempstore to in memory, but it's suboptimal since in that case all the RAM seems to be used up and I tend to run 4 or so of these processes in parallel. My (probably incorrect) assumption was that the iterator was a generator and would not put a large load on the memory, unlike e.g. fetchall which would load all rows. However I now run out of diskspace (on a small SSD scratch disk) and assuming that SQLite needs to store the results somewhere.

A way around this may be to run chunks of `SELECT ... LIMIT x OFFSET y` queries, but they get slower for each time a bigger `OFFSET` is used. Is there any other way to run this? What is stored in these temporary files? They seem to grow the further I iterate.

Comment: Does ist also happen if you only `pass` in the loop?

Comment: Yes, even just iterating through the results does the trick.

Comment: Do you have an index on `pid`? Can you post the output of `EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN <your query>`?

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo Added that, I also forgot a `DISTINCT` and tables are joined on pname not pid, should have copypasted it instead of typing. Both pid and pname are indexed. Seeing the output, is it the DISTINCT that generates the temp file?

Comment: Probably; SQLite needs to store the set of already-visited values somewhere, which is that `USE TEMP B-TREE FOR DISTINCT` entry. SQLite will swap it to disk if it gets too large.

Comment: You're right, removing `DISTINCT` fixes the crashing. If you'd like to turn that knowledge into an answer I can go and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
0|0|0|USE TEMP B-TREE FOR DISTINCT
```

Here's what's using the disk.

In order to support `DISTINCT`, SQLite has to store what rows already appeared in the query. For a large number of results, this set can grow huge. So to save on RAM, SQLite will temporarily store the distinct set on disk.

Removing the `DISTINCT` clause is an easy way to avoid the issue, but it changes the meaning of the query; you can now get duplicate rows. If you don't mind that, or you have unique indices or some other way of ensuring that you never get duplicates, then that won't matter.

Answer (score -1):

What you are trying to do with SQLite3 is a very bad idea, let me try to explain why.

You have the raw data on disk where it fits and is readable.

You generate a result inside of SQLite3 which expands greatly.

You then try to transfer this very large dataset through an sql connector.

Relational databases in general is not made for this kind of operation. SQLite3 is no exception. Relational databases were made for small quick queries that live for a fraction of a second and that returns a couple of rows.

You would be better off using another tool.

Reading the whole dataset into python using [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) for instance is my recommended solution. Also using [itertools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) is a good idea.

Comment: _SQL in general is not made for this kind of operation_ Um, yes it is; SQL is made for effectively working with large amounts of tabular data and joins.

Comment: I updated my answer, but I still think you are wrong. SQL as a language was not made with data amount in mind. It's just an abstraction.

Comment: "SQL as a language" is completely agnostic to the amount of data you need; you just specify "I want this data, join it with this, and only if it matches these conditions". Most databases (SQLite included) have query planners to figure out the best way to execute a SQL query; why would you bother using a query planner for a couple of rows? Also, SQLite reads the data from disk as necessary; how are you going to load a several gigabyte dataset into memory?

Comment: "'SQL as a language' is completely agnostic to the amount of data you need" this is basically what I said, so we agree. Query planners are needed even if you just want to return one row. I would argue they are the most efficient in this case. But all query planners are different. Redshift for instance has a query planner suited for larger amounts of data, they changed PostgreSQLs query planner to fit this purpose more. And lastly, a 3.5Mil dataset with id and name is not even a gigabyte. More like a couple of megabytes. But after the join, it is larger.

Comment: You don't need a query planner if all you want to support is looking up a few rows in an index. You do need one to efficiently support complex joins, which you're saying shouldn't be done in SQL. And SQLite doesn't keep the entire result in memory; the joined rows are fetched as needed and discarded when they aren't. Adding more joins just adds to the query time, not the resource usage.

Comment: The error that glormph is experiencing is just that the resources are running out, so my guess is that the data is not discarded. This is why I would do the join on the smaller dataset (3.5Mil) in memory to generate the larger dataset (55Mil) and discard each row after usage, since obviously glormph only needs to read one row at the time, generators are excellent for this task.

Comment: It's using resources because of the DISTINCT clause, which I already addressed. You definitely would need to keep each row after its usage with DISTINCT to check for duplicate rows.